# Porting PHP AES encryption to Golang

Tags: php, go, encryption, aes

My ecommerce provider has this library in PHP, Java, JavaScript, C# and Python to encrypt my request, since my API is made with Go, naturally I thought, why not do it with Go?

Oh boy... I didn't know what I was getting into.

Here's the original PHP code:

```php
class AesCrypto {
    /**
    * Encrypt string with a given key
    * @param strToEncrypt
    * @param key
    * @return String encrypted string
    */
    public static function encrypt($plaintext, $key128) {
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-128-cbc'));
        $cipherText = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'AES-128-CBC', hex2bin($key128), 1, $iv);
        return base64_encode($iv.$cipherText);
    }
}
```

I've tried several slightly different ways with Go, I guess the bare minimum is this:

```golang
func encrypt(text string, key string) string {
    data := []byte(text)
    block, _ := aes.NewCipher([]byte(key))
    gcm, err := cipher.NewGCM(block)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    nonce := make([]byte, gcm.NonceSize())
    if _, err = io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, nonce); err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    ciphertext := gcm.Seal(nonce, nonce, data, nil)
    encoded := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(ciphertext))
    return encoded
}
```

I have created this function to encrypt and the decrypt and they work fine, but when I send it to my provider it doesn't work.

The `key` is assigned by the ecommerce provider and it is 32 length byte, I understand that the length "tells" `newCipher` to select AES-256, right? then it will never correspond to a AES-128, as indicated in the PHP func.

Other than checking with my ecommerce provider's service or trying to decrypt using the PHP code, how do I go about porting this PHP code?

Here's another attempt (from the Go crypto docs):

```golang
func encrypt4(text string, keyString string) string {
    key, _ := hex.DecodeString(keyString)
    plaintext := []byte(text)
    if len(plaintext)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
        panic("plaintext is not a multiple of the block size")
    }

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(plaintext))
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
    mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], plaintext)
    final := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(ciphertext)
    return final
}
```

Comment: The key is hexadecimal, so 32 characters is 16 bytes, or aes-128. In your first example, you're using GCM, that's just never going to work. The second example looks better, but it's hard to tell without a full example with `text`, `keyString` and generated vs expected `iv` and `ciphertext`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCM is not the same as CBC mode. The key is hex encoded, so a 32 byte string represents a 16 byte (or 128 bit) key.

In CBC mode the plaintext must be padded so that it is a multiple of the block size. PHP's openssl_encrypt does this automatically (using [PKCS#5/7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS%235_and_PKCS%237)), but in Go it must be done explicitely.

Putting it all together we end up with a slight variation of the [CBC encryption example in the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/cipher/#example_NewCBCEncrypter):

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/aes"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base64"
    "encoding/hex"
    "io"
)

func encrypt(plaintext, key16 string) string {
    padded := pkcs7pad([]byte(plaintext), aes.BlockSize)

    key, err := hex.DecodeString(key16)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    buffer := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(padded)) // IV followed by ciphertext
    iv, ciphertext := buffer[:aes.BlockSize], buffer[aes.BlockSize:]

    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    mode := cipher.NewCBCEncrypter(block, iv)
    mode.CryptBlocks(ciphertext, padded)

    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(buffer)
}

func pkcs7pad(plaintext []byte, blockSize int) []byte {
    padding := blockSize - len(plaintext)%blockSize

    return append(plaintext, bytes.Repeat([]byte{byte(padding)}, padding)...)
}
```